# Actualización automática de atributos `timedelta` en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Estoy tratando de describir el comportamiento de unos objetos y necesito almacenar cuánto tiempo está activo cada uno de ellos. Por lo que recurro a `timedelta`:

```
import datetime

class Activos:
    def __init__(self, tinicio=datetime.datetime.now(), duracion=datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)):
        self.tinicio = tinicio
        self.duracion = duracion

    def cronos(self):
        aloha = datetime.datetime.now()-self.tinicio
        jour = aloha.days
        gundo = aloha.seconds
        self.duracion = datetime.timedelta(days=jour, seconds=gundo)
```

Ya que cuando hago:

```
....
def cronos(self):
    self.duracion = datetime.timedelta(datetime.datetime.now()-self.tinicio)
```

Aparece lo siguiente:

`# TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: datetime.datetime`

Mi pregunta es si se podría actualizar `Activos.duracion` automáticamente, **sin tener que llamar a una función (o método) que lo haga**.
¿Quizá tocando variables de inicialización?:

```
import datetime

class Momento:
    def __init__(self, tinicio=datetime.datetime.now(), duracion=datetime.timedelta(0)):
        self.tinicio = tinicio
        self.duracion = datetime.timedelta(datetime.datetime.now()-self.tinicio)
```

Pero entonces volvería a aparecer el mismo error.

Gracias por su tiempo (nunca mejor dicho :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al restar dos `datetimes` obtienes directamente un `timedelta`. No necesitas instanciar tú uno (y menos pasarle como parámetro la resta, pues entonces le estás pasando otro `timedelta`).

Un ejemplo:

```
import datetime
import time

t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
time.sleep(2)
t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
transcurrido = t2-t1

# Transcurrido ya es de tipo timedelta. Puedes imprimirlo pues
# tiene una conversión automática a cadena
print(transcurrido)

# Pero también puedes acceder a sus campos
print("Han pasado {} minutos y {} segundos con {} µsegundos".format(
    transcurrido.min, transcurrido.seconds, transcurrido.microseconds))
```

Resultado:

```html
0:00:02.002259
Han pasado -999999999 days, 0:00:00 minutos y 2 segundos con 2259 µsegundos
```

**Respondiendo a la pregunta en un comentario**

No existen atributos de clase que se actualicen "automáticamente", siempre debe haber algún código que lo haga. En todo caso, aún si tuvieras un campo `duracion` que se actualizara sólo mágicamente, en algún momento lo consultarás, digo yo. Por tanto ¿por qué no calcular ese atributo en el instante de la consulta?

Por ejemplo un mero cambio de nombre te da otra perspectiva:

```
import datetime

class Activos:
    def __init__(self, tinicio=datetime.datetime.now(), duracion=datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)):
        self.tinicio = tinicio
        self.duracion = duracion

    def get_duracion(self):
        self.duracion = datetime.datetime.now() - self.inicio
        return self.duracion

ej = Activos()
time.sleep(2)
print(ej.get_duracion())
```

```
0:00:02.002534
```

Pero aún podemos hacer otra cosa, que está ya muy cerca de la "actualización automática" que buscabas.

```
import datetime

class Activos:
    def __init__(self, tinicio=datetime.datetime.now(), duracion=datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)):
        self.tinicio = tinicio

    @property
    def duracion(self):
        return datetime.datetime.now() - self.tinicio

ej = Activos()
time.sleep(2)
print(ej.duracion)
```

En este caso el objeto no tiene realmente un atributo `duracion`, pero al declarar la función `duracion()` como `@property`, se ejecutará cuando intentes acceder al atributo `ej.duracion`, produciendo la "ilusión" de que es un atributo real y que tiene el tiempo transcurrido (cuando en realidad el resultado se computa en el momento de evaluarlo)

Comment: Entonces, ¿los atributos de clase que dependan del transcurso del tiempo, se pueden actualizar automáticamente?

Comment: No había entendido correctamente tu pregunta, y me había fijado sólo en el asunto de la conversión a `timedelta`. Acabo de actualizar la respuesta con información que creo que podría ser parecido a lo que buscas.

Comment: Lo he probado y funciona bien. Es bastante confuso porque repasando la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) había entendido que al hacer operaciones con objetos `datetime` el resultado era nuevamente otro objeto `datetime`.

Comment: @RubenGarcíaTutor Si buscas en esa página de documentación la cadena "Supported Operations" verás unas tablas que te muestran qué operaciones están definidas para estos tipos. Ahi dice que `timedelta = datetime1-datetime2`.